# Change shopt output

Tags: bash, shopt

Is there a way to change the output when shopt is invoked to something more verbose like a different color or a custom text?

For example:

```
~ >> shopt -s cdspell
~ >> cd Projectss
Projects # line outputted by shopt
~/Projects >>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not without changing the source code.  Looking at the source of Bash 5 (`cd_builtin()` function in `builtins/cd.def`) -- it just prints the suggested directory name, and format is not configurable at runtime (look for `LCD_DOSPELL`).